# Switching back from terminal (CTRL+ALT+Fn) takes a while on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, dell, ubuntu-gnome, nouveau

When I switch to a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd> etc.) and then switch back to graphical environment/Gnome (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>), I can see Gnome' screen for a very short period and then the screen gets dark. Then it takes about 10 seconds so I can see again the screen.

I noted this also occurs when I:

- switch to another user via Gnome graphical interface (switch not logging out);
- resume the laptop (after have suspended it).

I'm using a Dell notebook with NVIDIA graphic card (using proprietary driver).

Despite that, I also tried changing Nvidia graphic card driver to alternative open source Nouveau driver, and behavior is a little bit different: when I switch from terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> etc.) back to graphical environment (kbd>Ctrl + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>), I can immediately see the screen, but I can only click anything after same (more or less) 10 seconds.

Have you had also this behavior using Ubuntu 18.04? Do you think this could be a bug? Do you know any workaround?